# IF value in second row in column = X select second

Tags: sql, oracle

my query

```
select * from
(select * from
item
where (level_value = 'AT' or level_value='250004')
and effective_date < SYSDATE 
AND (expiration_date is null OR expiration_date > SYSDATE)
order by effective_date DESC)
where item_id = '12345'
```

I'd like to check for item_id =12345
IF value in second row in column level value = '250004' show only second row, if value in first row and second row in column level_value are the same - get only first row

How to do this using case/then?

For example:
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHC8N.png)

If level_value = 250004 is in the second row as on a screenshot in the result of the query, get second row. If level_value in first row ='AT' and in second row ='AT' in result of query get only first row

Comment: (1) Please provide sample data and desired results.  (2) There is no such thing as a "second row". SQL tables and queries (without an `ORDER BY` )represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, the order is crucial to understand what you mean with "second row"

Comment: The way I understood it, it is the 2nd row per each ITEM_ID, sorted by EFFECTIVE_DATE in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the requirement - you want to have as a result one record from a set of maximum 2 records - where the '250004' record is a better option, and the 'AT' is a backup plan, if I understood it correctly, then the following suggestion will work for you, with leveraging left join and oracle nvl function

```
    select 
    nvl(other.item_id,at.item_id) as item_id,
    nvl(other. level_value,at. level_value) as level_value,
    nvl(other.effective_date,at.effective_date) as effective_date,
    nvl(other.expiration_date,at.expiration_date) as expiration_date 
    from
        (select item_id,
        level_value,
        effective_date,
        expiration_date from item 
        where level_value = 'AT'
        AND nvl(expiration_date, SYSDATE-1)<SYSDATE) at
    left join 
        (select item_id,
        level_value,
        effective_date,
        expiration_date from item 
        where level_value = '250004'
        AND nvl(expiration_date, SYSDATE-1)<SYSDATE
        ) other
    on (at.item_id = other.item_id)
where nvl(other.item_id,at.item_id) = '12345'
order by effective_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     item (item_id,
  3           level_value,
  4           effective_date,
  5           expiration_date)
  6     AS
  7     -- sample data
  8        (SELECT '12345', 'AT', SYSDATE - 1, NULL FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT '12345', 'AT', SYSDATE - 2, NULL FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT '12345', '250004', SYSDATE - 3, SYSDATE + 1 FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT '2', '250004', SYSDATE, SYSDATE + 1 FROM DUAL),
```

---

```
 15     temp
 16     AS
 17     -- row numbers, partitioned by ITEM_ID, sorted by EFFECTIVE_DATE in descending order
 18        (SELECT i.*,
 19                ROW_NUMBER ()
 20                   OVER (PARTITION BY i.item_id ORDER BY i.effective_date DESC) rn
 21           FROM item i
 22          WHERE     i.item_id = '12345'
 23                AND (   i.level_value = 'AT'
 24                     OR i.level_value = '250004')
 25                AND i.effective_date < SYSDATE
 26                AND (   i.expiration_date IS NULL
 27                     OR i.expiration_date > SYSDATE))
 28  -- fetch 2nd row because LEVEL_VALUE = 250004
 29  SELECT *
 30    FROM temp
 31   WHERE     rn = 2
 32         AND level_value = '250004'
 33  UNION ALL
 34  -- fetch 1st row because LEVEL_VALUEs are the same for the 1st and the 2nd row
 35  SELECT *
 36    FROM temp
 37   WHERE rn = CASE
 38                 WHEN (SELECT level_value
 39                         FROM temp
 40                        WHERE rn = 1) = (SELECT level_value
 41                                           FROM temp
 42                                          WHERE rn = 2)
 43                 THEN 1 END;

ITEM_ LEVEL_ EFFECTIVE_ EXPIRATION         RN
----- ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
12345 AT     10.08.2021                     1

SQL>
```

If data is changed (see line #10) (the rest of code remains the same):

```
SQL> WITH
  2     item (item_id,
  3           level_value,
  4           effective_date,
  5           expiration_date)
  6     AS
  7     -- sample data
  8        (SELECT '12345', 'AT', SYSDATE - 1, NULL FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT '12345', '250004', SYSDATE - 2, NULL FROM DUAL          --> AT changed to 250004
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT '12345', '250004', SYSDATE - 3, SYSDATE + 1 FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT '2', '250004', SYSDATE, SYSDATE + 1 FROM DUAL),
 <snip>

ITEM_ LEVEL_ EFFECTIVE_ EXPIRATION         RN
----- ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
12345 250004 09.08.2021                     2

SQL>
```